# OSX Yosemite backup

Tags: macos, time-machine

I have a MBP running OSX Yosemite and the Time Machine backup has stopped working.

It's showing the following:

> OSX Yosemite time machine error: sparsebundle” could not be accessed
>   (error (null)).

Answer (score 0):

Can you open up the drive that you're trying to back up to?
See if there's an incomplete backup and delete if so, then retry.
Also  install [backupLoupe](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/31225/backuploupe) and see what the error messages it gives you are.
If you post them it should become clearer.